# DFA and equivalence classes: counting odd numbers of b's

Tags: formal-languages

I am studying for an exam and found an exercise about finding the equivalence classes for $L=a^*ba^*(ba^*ba^*)^*$, the language over $\{a,b\}^*$ with an odd number of b's.

We found three equivalence classes: $[a^*], [a^*ba^*(ba^*ba^*)^*], [a^*ba^*ba^*(ba^*ba^*)^*]$. This means the minimal DFA would have three states, and it was given so:

[image: 3-state DFA]

But it seemed to me that the following DFA with two states would achieve the same result (by merging q0 and q2).

[image: 2-state DFA]

This is a contradiction with having three equivalence classes.

What went wrong here, and where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first and third equivalence classes are equivalent to one another. They both contain strings in which there are an even number of $b$s: in the first class, that number is zero; in the third class, it's at least two.  For any string in either of those classes, adding a string with an odd number of $b$s gives a string in the language, and adding a string with an even number gives a string not in it.